# how to update duplicate mySQL records based on a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables called `db_carts` and `db_carts_items`.

The problem is that they may have different `sc_id` but the same `seller_id`.

I am trying to get ones that have duplicates (which I achieved with the query below) and then I need to update the duplicate ones so that for each different `seller_id` the `sc_id` is the same (the highest value of the matches, if possible).

How would I achieve this, preferably in mySQL or PHP?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM db_carts 
LEFT JOIN db_carts_items ON db_carts.sc_id=db_carts_items.sc_id
WHERE buyer_id="123456"
AND seller_id IN 
    ( SELECT seller_id
      FROM db_carts 
      WHERE buyer_id="123456"
      GROUP BY seller_id having (count(*) > 1)
    )
```

And that gives me an output like:

```
sc_id    |    seller_id    |    buyer_id    |
=============================================
15             50                123456
18             50                123456
23             70                123456
45             70                123456
```

And I need it to update `db_carts_items` so that it looks like:

```
sc_id    |    seller_id    |    buyer_id    |
=============================================
18             50                123456
18             50                123456
45             70                123456
45             70                123456
```

Is that in any way possible from mySQL? If not, in PHP?

I basically need to update the `sc_id` value in the `db_carts_items` table based on that output, for each of the duplicates.

Comment: do you need an order for `sc_id` ?

Comment: Not really. I just put it like that to make it easily readable. In fact they could be not in order when returned. The important thing is that the sc_id is updated to be a unique `sc_id` per `seller_id`.

Comment: i would create a temporary table using `CREATE TABLE tmp AS SELECT MIN(sc_id), seller_id GROUP BY seller_id`, then update the original table with something like `UPDATE A FROM db_carts_items AS A, tmp SET A.sc_id = tmp.sc_id WHERE A.seller_id=tmp.seller_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
with duplicates as (SELECT seller_id, max(sc_id) as maximum 
FROM db_carts 
WHERE buyer_id='123456'
GROUP BY seller_id
HAVING count(*)>1)
UPDATE db_carts, db_carts_items 
set db_carts.sc_id=duplicates.maximum, 
db_carts_items.sc_id=duplicates.maximum
FROM db_carts, db_carts_items, duplicates
WHERE db_carts.buyer_id='123456'
AND db_carts.seller_id=db_carts_items.seller_id 
AND db_carts.seller_id=duplicates.seller_id;
```

Edit: It seems like you can't use with on an update statement. In this case I would just do it with PHP.
First fetch the seller_id and their maximum

```
"SELECT seller_id, max(sc_id) as maximum 
FROM db_carts 
WHERE buyer_id='123456'
GROUP BY seller_id
HAVING count(*)>1"
```

Then for each returned row make an update like this

```
"UPDATE db_carts, db_carts_items 
set db_carts.sc_id=".$row['maximum'].", 
db_carts_items.sc_id=".$row['maximum'].
"FROM db_carts, db_carts_items
WHERE db_carts.buyer_id='123456'
AND db_carts.seller_id=db_carts_items.seller_id 
AND db_carts.seller_id=".$row['seller_id']
```

Comment: I might do something obviously wrong but I get a syntax error. Is the "WITH" supposed to be the first line?

Comment: Edited my answer. I didn't know that you can't use with on an update statement.